# Watt/Amp Hour, Watt/Amp Minute Confusion

Tags: power

I am somehow very confused about amp/watt hour and minutes. I am trying to size a battery to see how much load I can get away with before it hits the 50% discharge zone.

I plan on connecting a modified sine wave inverter (3.6W idle), microcontroller (14W max) that will be attached to the inverter, an actuator (*motor<sup>1</sup>*), and rotisserie motor (*motor<sup>2</sup>*).

My problem is that *motor<sup>1</sup>* has an inrush current of 4.6A and the *motor<sup>2</sup>* has one of 10A. Talking to the makers of both, it appears these happen almost instantaneously for about 0.2 sec at worst case when they both start and stop due to inertia.

Otherwise *motor<sup>1</sup>* draws 3.2A and *motor<sup>2</sup>* draws 5.5A (both run 12V). For both motors they will only be on when they need to be turned and they will only be in motion for at most 2 min at each time.

This is a school experiment so I'll estimate I would run each motor 30 times in a day during the same time the controller and inverter are on. How would I go about calculating how much load I would consuming?

Comment: How long are you going to run the motors each time? Do they just start and stop?

Comment: General tutorial on amp-hour, watt-hour etc.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxkVxi9P0EA

Comment: 14W? That's some microcontroller!

Comment: Eric, at most each time 2 minutes. And yeah the just start and stop, nothing more. the microcontroller is supposed to tell it when to start and stop. Brian, the 14W is for the MyRio and its a worst case scenario. Mostly likely won't touch that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you ignore the start-up inrush since it is so quick and the overcurrent is small.

So, you have a total load of 3.2 + 5.5 = 8.7 A at 12 V for 2 minutes, 30 times...

That is 8.7 A Hr per day for the motors.

The inverter will use 3.6W = 3.6/12 A. That is 0.3A. so in a day that is 0.3 x 24 A Hr. = 7.2 A Hr

The microcontroller (14 W seems a lot, as the other person commented) will use 14/3.6 x 7.2 = 28 A Hr.

Total = 8.7 + 7.2 + 28 = 44 A Hr per day.

That controller is going to require a big battery. The motors hardly any...

Comment: yeah the 14W is absolute max for the NI MyRio controller. Its the worst case scenario. I will say for the actuator worst case scenario is 4.6A according to Amazon, the maker of the actuator said it was 3.2 though. Do you know if Walmart Deep Cycle Marine batteries would be good for this kind of application? It says its rated at 101AH http://www.walmart.com/ip/EverStart-Group-Size-24DC-Marine-Battery/20531540

Comment: Why did you divide 14W by 3.6W and then multiply 7.2. Could you explain the math. And as for the inverter, it will be on only when I am running experiments. I would disconnect it after each session. Each session at worst being 5 hours a day.

Comment: I scaled the result that I got for 3.6 W up to 14 W, rather than working it out afresh, hence 14/3.6 x 7.2 for the number of ampere hours for the 14 W.

Comment: Deep cycle batteries are the correct type to use for this. I suggest that you measure the actual power consumption of your MyRio in the application. It will be well less than the 14 W and then you can use a smaller cheaper battery. :)

Comment: Yah I plan on it. But I still don't understand what you mean that you scaled the Rio up. 14W is the max which probably won't happen. So why scale it up. Or is that your way of getting the current ratio it would be getting from the inverter? Normally I just just did 14Whr and multipled it by 5 hour, prbly the most a day I would be using it. I then subtracted the Wh from the battery and then converted the remaining battery Watth back into AH and did the rest of your calculations

Comment: I worked out how many A Hr were required for the load of 3.6 W. That was 7.2. Then I needed to work out how many were required for 14 W. I could have done the same calculation again but instead I recognized that it was the same calculation and that the result would just be 14/3.6 x as big... so I multiplied the 7.2 by that ratio. I was using 24 Hr because that was what you specified in the original formulation of the problem.